# Burninate [reset]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The [reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reset) tag  seems wholly unnecessary.

- Used in a wide variety of contexts for all kinds of issues and languages.
- Has the description "Resetting something restores it to a default position or value, or to a previous position or value", which is both broad and vague.
- No one can be an expert at resetting and it has six followers.
- It is not useful.

It meets all the criteria of to [When to burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191):

- Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?
  No and no
- Is the concept described even on-topic for the site? No
- Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post? Nope
- Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts? No

Can we burninate it?

Comment: A more worthy tag for burnination I've nary seen

Comment: "A new question in [reset]! I'm an expert at that!" - No one.

Comment: Shift and reset seem to be important for [delimited continuations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimited_continuation).

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I agree, [reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reset) is *extremely* ambiguous, and can cover *many* things such as:

- Password resets
- Resetting settings of an application to defaults
- Resetting a variable
- Resetting the processing state

...to name a few.

Many questions tagged [reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reset) don't need the tag for starters, and it also attracts [off-topic questions such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28102992/android-os-update-and-factory-reset).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753597/ipod-cant-work-as-development-device-after-reset :)

Comment: don't forget about the reset input element!

Comment: "rebooting" your computer, since the button often said "reset"

Comment: Well this was a good start 3 years ago although this tag still seems to be a problem to me.