# [page-numbering]'s days are numbered

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[page-numbering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/page-numbering) has 164 questions and its wiki explanation is:

> Refers to the common task of numbering pages.

### Burnination criteria

> 1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

No, the contents of the questions are always related to another topic, usually a document generation/conversion problem:

- [LateX - Page numbering on white page with chapters starting on right hand side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44452836/latex-page-numbering-on-white-page-with-chapters-starting-on-right-hand-side)
- [Set the last page number to a fixed value in moderncv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68292084/set-the-last-page-number-to-a-fixed-value-in-moderncv)
- [AdminLTE. table page change 1 to other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43388018/adminlte-table-page-change-1-to-other)
- [Wordpress Page-Navi Error 400 Custom Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42757245/wordpress-page-navi-error-400-custom-template)

> 2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Sometimes. The concept could be always on-topic on dedicated sites like [tex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

> 3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No, because the answer itself contains always the information related to "page numbering". E.g.:

- [PDF Page Numbering in Java & iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205777/pdf-page-numbering-in-java-itext)
- [Google Docs - Table of contents with paging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23732714/google-docs-table-of-contents-with-paging)
- [How to start page numbering in R Markdown from the second page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38765422/how-to-start-page-numbering-in-r-markdown-from-the-second-page)

> 4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No, it has been also used in a question about "memory pages":

- [Page number and offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628671/page-number-and-offset)
- [Scrape multiple pages with BeautifulSoup and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26497722/scrape-multiple-pages-with-beautifulsoup-and-python)
- [How to find the page number from a paragraph using OpenXML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14936701/how-to-find-the-page-number-from-a-paragraph-using-openxml)

### Further consideration

I don't think that [page-numbering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/page-numbering) can be a [pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pagination) synonym because they have two different meanings. The first one is about adding numbers to a page in a document, while the second one is about the process of dividing a set of entries in multiple pages (e.g. a page of a table).
Moreover, scrolling through the 164 [page-numbering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/page-numbering) questions, you can find only four [pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pagination) related questions:

- [how to use pagination with an array filled out by http request | Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52671665/how-to-use-pagination-with-an-array-filled-out-by-http-request-angular-6)
- [Changing pagination from 20 to 10 records per page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959858/changing-pagination-from-20-to-10-records-per-page)
- [django pisa - pagenumber just for two or more pages - show pagenumber of total pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732478/django-pisa-pagenumber-just-for-two-or-more-pages-show-pagenumber-of-total-p)
- [Displaying page numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448913/displaying-page-numbers)

Comment: Looks like it's also used on some questions about getting page numbers in collections (eg. when you do a GET query and want to page the results) -- eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25604384/how-can-i-get-server-side-pagination-in-ng-grid-in-angularsjs

Comment: Just to note that Tex questions are on-topic and accepted on SO so if it makes sense on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ then it should make sense on Tex questions on SO as well so maybe renaming might be more appropriate (e.g. [tex-page-numbering]) though it honestly does look very narrow for a tag

Comment: Isn't it all just [tag:pagination]?

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing. Maybe we just need to synonym this to [pagination]

Comment: All of it isn't. [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71352775/page-numbering-in-word-documents-created-with-officer), which asks specifically about page numbering in word documents through code. The question mentions a few more examples of this. I feel like synonimizing doesn't really make sense. Might make more sense to remove all the questions asking about page numbers, and merge the rest into [pagination] without a synonym

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine Good point. A retag would make sense

Comment: I've updated the proposal with some consideration about [pagination]

Comment: I won't, but you could argue that the process of assigning page numbers in a Word Document is still pagination. Admittedly, the tag wiki is a bit sparse.

Comment: If you are creating a Word doc using OpenXML, page numbering is just one of the gazillion things your care about.  In general, it just works (much like how page numbering in Word just works).  Sometimes you need to change the automatic behavior, but at that point, it's off to the documentation and/or the OpenXML SDK Productivity Tool, just like when trying to implement some other obscure feature.

Comment: @PeterMortensen, I'm not sure it even makes the top 10.

Comment: *"Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?
No, because the answer itself contains always the information related to "page numbering"*" So if we write "python" in all questions related to Python we no longer need the [tag:python] tag?

Comment: @CrisLuengo and that's why the argument for searchability is flawed. Tags primary clients are answeres. Unlike python where you can tell if your knowledge could be relevant, page-numbering isn't a topic that you can say "I should know the answer about this".

Comment: It looks like its days are numbered, and it has been weighed in the balances and found wanting, but its kingdom has not yet been divided. Can the Medes and Persians please come burninate it?

Answer (score 6):

> the contents of the questions are always related to another topic, usually a document generation/conversion problem

I don't see how that makes the tag ambiguous. Numbering pages in documents is exactly what [page-numbering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/page-numbering) is about. We should clarify the tag description, and cleanup the usage of the tag.

It should be removed from the [os memory pages question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628671/page-number-and-offset), the [website navigation question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26497722/scrape-multiple-pages-with-beautifulsoup-and-python), the [wordpress website pagination question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42757245/1048572), the [array pagination question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52671665/how-to-use-pagination-with-an-array-filled-out-by-http-request-angular-6), the [sql pagination question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959858/changing-pagination-from-20-to-10-records-per-page) and the [table pagination question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43388018/1048572),
but not from the [word document question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14936701/how-to-find-the-page-number-from-a-paragraph-using-openxml) or the [conditional page numbering question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10732478/1048572).

I'm split on whether it should be used for numbering of pages created by a pagination algorithm for a list, these are not strictly documents but could sometimes be. I guess if it's not strictly about custom numbering requirements, the [pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pagination) questions should not have it.

Like you pointed out, it's definitely not a [pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pagination) synonym.

The topic is neither strictly off-topic, nor does the tag do any harm (when used correctly), so I don't think it should be burninated.

Comment: I don't think that a tag with 164 questions over 12 years, without being a real skill or technology or tool, can be considered a good tag. From my point of view, noise is harmful - if you have too many tags, they lost their usefulness.

Comment: @lifeisfoo What does this have to do with the number of questions using the tag? Usefulness is not the same as usage. There's no harm unless you can find a question where using [page-numbering] prevents a more appropriate tag from being applied.

Comment: I agree, it does no harm. There are many tags out there that do cause harm and we don't do anything about those because nobody has time.

Comment: Agreed, I didn't really understand this response to the first question. It seems quite unambiguous. (I also don't agree with the response to question 3)

Comment: @CrisLuengo what would be one of such tag?

Comment: @Braiam How about [this hot mess](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385792/7328782)? But even things such as [\[reset\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285603/7328782) are way more ambiguous than [page-numbering] will ever be, and that was pointed out 7 years ago.

Comment: @CrisLuengo well, here's the thing, if you had started working on any of those at a 5 question/day it's very unlikely that you wouldn't have finished by now. I've "fixed" tags in a day when they are less than 50, because the last time I tried to do that with a bigger tag I was suspended. So, yeah, instead of saying "look this tag is also bad" maybe invest more effort saying "we should do less talking and more doing with tag moderation". Just start doing it, and as long as nobody complains, it will happen eventually.